# Factory Girl says ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have a `factories.rb` file that includes

```
factory :link do
  employer
  sequence(:link) {|n| "testlink#{n}" }
  name  "Test Link"
  channel_cost 200
end

factory :matching do
  candidate
  job
  link              # ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)

  after(:create) { |matching|
    job = matching.job
    job.employer = matching.employer
    job.save(validate: false)
  }
end
```

employer, candidate, and job are all defined above the factories shown. I'm getting an error at 'link' that doesn't make much sense to me.

Also, when I comment out that single line (`link`), it works.

What arguments does it want, and how do I add them?

Comment: @RichardHamilton It doesn't. The errors are pointing at different locations (other OP's error is pointing at class and mine is pointing at factories.rb) and it's not obvious they are being caused by the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `:link` factory definition,

```
sequence(:link) { |n| "testlink#{n}" }
```

defines a sequence named `:link`.

In the `:matching` factory definition, factory_girl seems to be interpreting `link` not as an association to a `Link`, but as an attribute `link` which you want to fill with the next value in the sequence named `:link`. (Documented [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences).)

Renaming your sequence should fix the problem.